# Read variable number of properties from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, dynamic

Say I have this function signature:

```
export const readVariableProps = function(obj: Object, props: Array<string>) : any {

   // props => ['a','b','c']
   return obj['a']['b']['c'];

}
```

obviously, props is a variable length array, with an unknown list or properties to read from the given object.

is the only way to get this kind of dynamic behavior to use `eval()`?

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want [obj['a'],obj['b'],...] as per your title ? or obj[a][b]... as per your code sample ?

Comment: I think jfriend00 got what I was looking for, thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the equivalent of `return obj['a']['b']['c'];` where `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` are the values in the array like you show in your question, you can do something like this (you may have to convert some details to typeScript):

```
export const readVariableProps = function(obj: Object, props: Array<string>) : any {
   return props.reduce(function(prior, next) {
       return prior[next];
   }, obj);
}
```

FYI, this type of scenario is exactly what `.reduce()` was designed for - 
accumulating a value that is built by visiting every item in an array.

This will throw if anything other than the last property in the array does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for..of` loop to set a variable to each nested property

```js
const props = ['a','b','c'];
const obj = {a:{b:{c:123}}};

let res;
for (let prop of props) res = !res ? obj[prop] : res[prop];

console.log(res);
```